# Using Redirect from jQuery using data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string, querystringparameter

I have a URL generated by the server. Being in the client I don't know if the URL will be : `http://url/parameter` or `http://url/parameter?anotherPar=1` .

this value is available to a javascript variable:

```
  var theUrl = '{someURLgeneratedByTheServer}';
```

I'd like to use `window.location.href` passing some parameters, but I can't just do it:

```
  window.location.href = theUrl + '?someClientGeneratedParameter=value&secondParameter=value2';
```

for this would be invalid if the server-generated URL already has some querystring parameters. I know that when I'm using jQuery's Ajax method I can use the options parameter passing the data object with the needed querystring parameters, and jQuery itself is able to decide wheter it has to concat with ? or &, like this:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: theUrl,
            data: {someClientGeneratedParameter:'value', secondParameter:'value2'},
            success: callback 
        });
```

Is there a way to make a redirection using this concat mechanism of jquery before calling `location.href`? (something like below):

```
//supposition only, when  theUrl equals 'http://url/parameter?anotherPar=1'
var finalUrl = $.getMyFinalUrl({url: theUrl,
                 data: {someClientGeneratedParameter:'value', secondParameter:'value2'}
                });
window.location.href = finalUrl ;
```

Does it make sense or should I write my own method?

Thanks.

PS: using Asp.net MVC3 on the server + C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this? Rip out the demo code and it's very simple and let's you pass parameters by array:

```
function getURL(theUrl, extraParameters) {
    var extraParametersEncoded = $.param(extraParameters);
    var seperator = theUrl.indexOf('?') == -1 ? "?" : "&";

    return(theUrl + seperator + extraParametersEncoded);
}


// Test1
var theUrl1 = "http://example.com/test"
var extraParameters1 = {
    "someClientGeneratedParameter": "value",
    "secondParameter": "value2"
};
alert(getURL(theUrl1, extraParameters1));

// Test2
var theUrl2 = "http://example.com/?test=test"
var extraParameters2 = {
    "someClientGeneratedParameter": "value",
    "secondParameter": "value2"
};  
alert(getURL(theUrl2, extraParameters2));
```

Output:

> http://example.com/test?someClientGeneratedParameter=value&secondParameter=value2 
>   http://example.com/?test=test&someClientGeneratedParameter=value&secondParameter=value2

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjuqG/

Comment: That is what I wanted, the `param` function, together with the functionality of making an automatic verification of the indexOf. I imagined jQuery would let this available and not only use inside `ajax` and `post` methods. Thanks!

I found out that using the jQuery BBQ (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) , I probably could do someting like `return $.param.querystring( theUrl, $.param(extraParameters))` inside the `getURL` method.

I appreciate.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

A simple expression to check the url before appending data should suffice:

`location.href.match(/(\?|&)anotherPar($|&|=)/)`

That will tell you if you need to append `?` or `&`.

Comment: but if I don't know the name of the `anotherPar`?

Comment: that would make it easier. instead of using an expression just use indexOf to check for a question mark in the url:
`if(location.href.indexOf("?") != -1)`